# Dagger 2 - How to establish sibling dependency via Subcomponent or Component Dependency

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

> **Background**

As per [docs](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents.html) dependency between sibling subcomponents is not possible so, the other way left is Component Dependency. I'm trying to encapsulate "Repository" class so that UI can only access the instance of "Repository", not implementation details of "Repository". I mean nothing from *ApiModule* should be exposed.

*ApiModule*

```
@Module
class ApiModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideConnection(): Connection = //....   
}
```

*RepositoryModule*

```
@Module (
    includes = [
        ApiModule::class
    ]
)
abstract class RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesRepository(connection Connection): Repository = //.....
}
```

*AppComponent*

```
@Component (modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    RepositoryModule::class
])
interface AppComponent{
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

> **Problem**

Now, if I create a subcomponent (let's say *ActivitySubComponent*) of *AppComponent*, all binding in *RepositoryModule* and *ApiModule* modules will be exposed to that subcomponent. Though, I want only provided "Repository" to be accessible from *ActivitySubComponent*

> **Proposed Solution**

Create *RepositoryComponenet* and *ActivityComponent* components make *AppComponenet* their dependency:

*AppComponent*

```
@Component (modules = [
    AppModule::class
])
interface AppComponent{
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

*ActivityComponent*

```
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class], modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{

        fun appComponent(appComponent: AppComponent): Builder

        fun build(): ActivityComponent
    }
}
```

*RepositoryComponent*

```
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class], modules = [RepositoryModule::class])
interface RepositoryComponent {
}
```

The problem is how do I expose "Repository" instance into sibling *ActivityComponent*'s bindings or `@Inject` into MainActivity? Any explanation, proposal to change my configuration or links to articles that may potentially solve my problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't want to expose all dependencies from AppComponent to its child components. As [component documentation](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/index.html?dagger/Component.html) says (section Component dependencies),

> Note that only the bindings exposed as provision methods are available through component dependencies.

you should use Component dependencies for this purpose.

Working example is below

```
class Connection
interface Repository

@Module
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideConnection() = Connection()
}

@Module(includes = [AppModule::class])
object RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(connection: Connection) = object : Repository {}
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, RepositoryModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    val repository: Repository
}

@Scope
@MustBeDocumented
@kotlin.annotation.Retention
annotation class ActivityScope

@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(activity: FakeActivity)
}

class FakeActivity {
    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: Repository
    //    uncomment this and code won't compile because connection isn't explicitly exposed in AppComponent
    //    @Inject
    //    lateinit var connection: Connection
}

fun main() {
    val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create()
    val activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder().appComponent(appComponent).build()
    val fakeActivity = FakeActivity()
    activityComponent.inject(fakeActivity)
    println("hash: ${fakeActivity.repository}")
    println("hash: ${appComponent.repository}")
}
```

I used scopes because I suppose you want just one instance of Repository per Application. If something is not clear, let me know.